# countif excel with value in column A or column B

Tags: excel, countif

I want to use `COUNTIF` in Excel, but I want to count rows where `column V = yes OR column U = yes`, with all the other criteria the same.

It is easy to use `or` with values in 1 column, such as `P4:P999 = "apple" or "orange"`, but how to use `or` over multiple columns?

Below is an Excel code sample written to be readable. The only solution I found was to use addition and rewrite the entire code, but I hate this solution because it is too long.

```
SUM(COUNTIFS(
     P4:P9999,  {"apple", "orange"}, 
     B4:B9999, "potato",
     AF4:AF9999, "",
     V4:V9999,  "Yes"
    )
) + 
SUM(COUNTIFS(
     P4:P9999,  {"apple", "orange"},
     B4:B9999, "potato",
     AF4:AF9999,  "",
     U4:U9999,  "Yes"
   )
)
```

Comment: With that approach you will also need to subtract where both `V` and `U` are `Yes` or they will be counted twice.

Comment: So glad you said that haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((P4:P9999 = "apple")+(P4:P9999 = "orange"))*(B4:B999="potato")*(LEN(AF4:AF999)=0)*((V4:V9999="Yes)+(U4:U9999="Yes")>0))
```

Comment: Any chance you can add a quick explanation of the code?

Comment: `*` is `AND` and `+` is `OR`.  `TRUE` becomes `1` and `FALSE` becomes `0`.  Then it is just math.